# SolrJ - RemoteSolrException raised connecting to Solr 5.5.4

Tags: java, maven, solr, solrj

I tried to connect Solr 5.5.4 using java with SolrJ jar, but Solr does not connect. it is get some errors.

```
try{
    String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/#/gettingstarted";
    HttpSolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient(urlString);
    QueryResponse queryResponse = solrClient.query(new SolrQuery("*:*"));
    System.out.println(queryResponse.toString());
} catch (SolrServerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Geting error:

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/#/gettingstarted: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->

<head>

  <title>Solr Admin</title>

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico?_=5.5.4">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/common.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/analysis.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/cloud.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/cores.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/dashboard.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/dataimport.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/files.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/index.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/java-properties.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/logging.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/menu.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/plugins.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/documents.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/query.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/replication.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/schema-browser.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/threads.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles/segments.css?_=5.5.4">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/chosen.css?_=5.5.4">

  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">

  <script type="text/javascript">

  var app_config = {};

  app_config.solr_path = '\/solr';
  app_config.core_admin_path = '\/admin\/cores';

  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">

      <a href="./" id="solr"><span>Apache SOLR</span></a>

      <p id="environment">&nbsp;</p>

    </div>

    <div id="main" class="clearfix">

      <div id="init-failures">

          <h2>SolrCore Initialization Failures</h2>
          <ul></ul>
          <p>Please check your logs for more information</p>

      </div>

      <div class="other-ui-link">
        Try <a class="ul" href="/solr/index.html">New UI</a><a target="_blank" href="http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AngularUI">&nbsp;<span class="help"></span></a>
      </div>

      <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="content">

          &nbsp;

        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="menu-wrapper">
        <div>

          <ul id="menu">

            <li id="index" class="global"><p><a href="#/">Dashboard</a></p></li>

            <li id="logging" class="global"><p><a href="#/~logging">Logging</a></p>
              <ul>
                <li class="level"><a href="#/~logging/level">Level</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="cloud" class="global optional"><p><a href="#/~cloud">Cloud</a></p>
              <ul>
                <li class="tree"><a href="#/~cloud?view=tree">Tree</a></li>
                <li class="graph"><a href="#/~cloud">Graph</a></li>
                <li class="rgraph"><a href="#/~cloud?view=rgraph">Graph (Radial)</a></li>
                <li class="dump"><a href="#/~cloud">Dump</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li id="cores" class="global"><p><a href="#/~cores">Core Admin</a></p></li>

            <li id="java-properties" class="global"><p><a href="#/~java-properties">Java Properties</a></li>

            <li id="threads" class="global"><p><a href="#/~threads">Thread Dump</a></p></li>

          </ul>

          <div id="core-selector">
            <div id="has-cores">
              <select data-placeholder="Core Selector"></select>
            </div>
            <p id="has-no-cores"><a href="#/~cores">
              No cores available
              <span>Go and create one</span>
            </a></p>
          </div>
          <div id="core-menu">
            <ul></ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="meta">

        <ul>

          <li class="documentation"><a href="http://lucene.apache.org/solr/"><span>Documentation</span></a></li>
          <li class="issues"><a href="http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR"><span>Issue Tracker</span></a></li>
          <li class="irc"><a href="https://wiki.apache.org/solr/IRCChannels"><span>IRC Channel</span></a></li>
          <li class="mailinglist"><a href="http://lucene.apache.org/solr/resources.html#community"><span>Community forum</span></a></li>
          <li class="wiki-query-syntax"><a href="https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Query+Syntax+and+Parsing"><span>Solr Query Syntax</span></a></li>

        </ul>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="connection_status">

    <span>Connection lost &hellip;</span>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript"> var require = { urlArgs: '_=5.5.4' }; </script>
  <script src="js/require.js?_=5.5.4" data-main="js/main"></script>

</body>
</html>

    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:545)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:230)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:149)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:942)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:957)
    at com.test.solr.SOLRTEST.App.main(App.java:38)
```

assure my solr running screenshot i attached below,
[image]

kindly please help me, thanks for advance.

Comment: I search and find many links, but these are does not help to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the Url without the anchor `#`, this should be the correct way.

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted";
HttpSolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient(urlString);
```

I assume that `gettingstarted` is the name of the collection you're using.

Comment: thanks mr.freedev, thank you very much sir, this solution working fine. But, I have some doubt sir, "http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted" - when i used this url browser shows 404(not found) error, "http://localhost:8983/solr/#/gettingstarted" - this url shows solr admin UI, How could i get correct out in this scenario with out "#" url.

Comment: you can see "localhost:8983/solr/#/gettingstarted" output for above attached screen-shot.

Comment: Your question, why the `#` (anchor tag or hash tag) make so much difference in our case, depends from how URL are build and who read that url. If the reader is a server (Solr for example), a web application or a browser. Strictly in our case the difference is between how is used by the Solr Admin UI and between Solr and SolrJ. I strongly suggest to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL (the syntax and fragment part)

Comment: I suggest to open a new question trying to clearly write your doubt about. I'll be glad to try to give you an answer.

Comment: I request you please give me some more best practice links for solr and solrj sir.